# PostgreSql: Canceled on conflict out to old pivot

Tags: postgresql

We have a PostgreSql 15 server serving around 30 databases, one schema each, with the same layout. Each database is used by one application instance. The application consistently uses transactions with isolation level serializable to access the database, optimizing by using explicit read only transactions, where applicable.
Once the server reaches 100% CPU load, we get an increased number of serializable conflict errors. This is expected, due to more concurrent access. But I fail to explain this kind of error:

```
ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
  Detail: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, with conflict out to old committed transaction 61866959.
```

There is a variation of the error:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
  Detail: Reason code: Canceled on conflict out to old pivot 61940806.
```

(The lanes are parallel transactions. The grey ones committed normally, the red ones failed. The big red transaction ran for 2h. Most of the short red transactions belong to a different DB than the long tx, and they conflict with a tx on their own DB, which committed 1:55h before. Once the long tx ended operation on all DBs continues normally.)

My understanding of serializable isolation is that only transactions which can somehow affect each other can conflict. It should be clear for PostgreSql, that transactions belonging to different databases cannot affect each other. But I'm seeing exactly this behavior. Can transactions on different DBs cause serializable conflicts? Maybe in high-load scenarios, where information in internal structures is consolidated?

[image: transactions]

Comment: The post doesn't include sufficient information to ascertain the transactions' dependencies. Please update the post with additional transaction related details.

Comment: How did you determine commit time of the old transaction?  When did the transaction getting the error begin?  Can you describe what each transaction would be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The awesome PostgreSql dev team [helped me understand the issue](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/590f3e4d-a561-43aa-b4a6-ee72387af275%40iki.fi).

While a serializable transaction is running, PostgreSql keeps track of what the transactions accesses. The space to store this information (shared memory) is limited. The longer a transaction runs, the more likely PostgreSql runs out shared memory. In order to keep the DB operational, PostgreSql swaps out this info to disk. It consolidates the information doing so, detail is lost. Most importantly, the database ID is not part of the swapped out information. Once this happens, it is possible that a transaction on one database causes (false positive) serializable isolation conflicts on another databases. This state keeps on, until the long running transaction finally commits, or rolls back.

The key takeaway here is clear: keep transactions short.